# Copy one array values to the the others

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, lodash

I have below array of JSON. I want to set schedules for the `dayOfWeek` which are not present inside the `schedules` of the other `rooms`

```
const data = {
  rooms: [
    {
      roomId: 1,
      schedules: []
    },
    {
      roomId: 2,
      schedules: [
        { home1: "05:05", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "20:30" },
        { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "21:30" },
        { home1: "07:05", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "22:30" }
      ]
    },
    {
      roomId: 3,
      schedules: []
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to copy the same schedules to the other rooms as well.

expected output

```
const finalArray = [
  { home1: "05:05", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "20:30", roomId: 1 }, //schedules from room2
  { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "21:30", roomId: 1 }, //schedules from room2
  { home1: "07:05", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "22:30", roomId: 1 }, //schedules from room2 

  { home1: "05:05", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "20:30", roomId: 3 }, //schedules from room2
  { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "21:30", roomId: 3 }, //schedules from room2
  { home1: "07:05", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "22:30", roomId: 3 }, //schedules from room2 
]
```

I have tried but could not get it work!!! Please help!!!

Comment: Should the final array be a new array or is it the rooms array? Or do you want to copy the schedules from roomId2 to the other rooms schedules array?

Comment: @JustAMicrobe Its a new array.

Comment: well what to do with the one which contains schedules ?

Comment: @CodeManiac Need to copy to the other rooms schedules. Contains `roomId`. Please have a look at the `finalArray`

Comment: Well you didn't added roomId 2 there you want it there or not in finalArray ?

Comment: @CodeManiac No I don't want roomId2.

Comment: will there be more than one room having sechdules ? what in to do in that case ?

Comment: @CodeManiac No only one `room` has the `schedules` always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first find the `source of truth room` and then use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to extract/copy the schedules to the others:

```js
const data = { rooms: [ { roomId: 1, schedules: [] }, { roomId: 2, schedules: [ { home1: "05:05", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "20:30" }, { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "21:30" }, { home1: "07:05", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "22:30" } ] }, { roomId: 3, schedules: [] } ] }

const theRoom = data.rooms.find(x => x.schedules.length)
const result = data.rooms.reduce((r,{roomId, schedules}) => {
  if(roomId != theRoom.roomId)
     r.push(...theRoom.schedules.map(x => ({ roomId, ...x })))
  return r
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: What are the arguments inside the `array.reduce(argument, argument)`?

Answer (score 1):

Just go through the array.

EDITED: edited by comment

```js
const data = {
  rooms: [
    {
      roomId: 1,
      schedules: []
    },
    {
      roomId: 2,
      schedules: [
        { home1: "05:05", dayOfWeek: 1, away: "20:30" },
        { home1: "06:05", dayOfWeek: 5, away: "21:30" },
        { home1: "07:05", dayOfWeek: 7, away: "22:30" }
      ]
    },
    {
      roomId: 3,
      schedules: []
    }
  ]
}

var roomIdWithSchedules = null;
var schedulesOfRoomWithRoomIdWithSchedules = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.rooms.length; i++) {
  if(data.rooms[i].schedules && data.rooms[i].schedules.length) {
    roomIdWithSchedules = data.rooms[i].roomId;
    schedulesOfRoomWithRoomIdWithSchedules = data.rooms[i].schedules.map(function(x) {
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));
    });
    break;
  }
}

var finalArray = [];
if(roomIdWithSchedules != null) {
  for(var i = 0; i < data.rooms.length; i++) {
    if(roomIdWithSchedules === data.rooms[i].roomId) {
      continue;
    }
    
    for(var j = 0; j < schedulesOfRoomWithRoomIdWithSchedules.length; j++) {
      var item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(schedulesOfRoomWithRoomIdWithSchedules[j]));
      item.roomId = data.rooms[i].roomId;
      finalArray.push(item)
    }
  }
}

console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: I am getting `roomId: 2` I need others `roomId` i.e. `1` and `3`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to simply put it into new array just do it:

```
var schedular = data.rooms[1].schedules
```